# Android Floating Window

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a red overlay window. You can see my code below. when i click button it does not do anything. Where is the problem? How can i fix this. Please make suggestions
Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OverlayLayer.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
}


public class OverlayLayer extends Service {

public IBinder onBind(Intent ıntent) {
    return null;
}
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private WindowManager mManager;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,0));
    mLayout.setLayoutParams(mParams);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(400,150,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    parameters.x=0;
    parameters.y=0;
    parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    mManager.addView(mLayout,parameters);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You just want to fill the screen with red on button click?

Comment: no. i just want to draw red rectangle over screen

Answer (score 0):

First add your Service in AndroidManifest by making it "static" because its in you MainActivity.java file :

```
<service android:name=".MainActivity$OverlayLayer"/>

//make class static
public static class OverlayLayer extends Service {
...
}
```

Or Create a stand-alone (separate from MainActivity) class like OverlayLayer.java and add it in Manifest file like :

```
<service android:name=".OverlayLayer"/>
```

After that use following code to add view in window :

Flag to add view on window depends on OS, So following code will make it work on each OS :

In **OverlayLayer** class :

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
            mLayout.setLayoutParams(mParams);


            addToWindow(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        }


        public void addToWindow(int LAYOUT_FLAG) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(400, 150, LAYOUT_FLAG, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            parameters.x = 0;
            parameters.y = 0;
            parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            try {

                mManager.addView(mLayout, parameters);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                if (LAYOUT_FLAG == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT) {
                    addToWindow(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
                }
                if (LAYOUT_FLAG == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST) {
                    addToWindow(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
                }
                if (LAYOUT_FLAG == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) {
                    addToWindow(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work on android 6, 7, 8. i dont know what am i going to do with this?

Comment: i add permission to android manifest. and it start to crash. i did some research and i found that error: is your activity running.

Comment: whats error it is showing can post it here complete error?

Comment: you can add it as standalone class Ex. OverlayLayer.java like MainActivity.java